# Double become long again when save to array

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, double

I wish to save some Double to an array, and I just need to have 2 decimal places Double. So I rounded the origin double to 2 decimal places, and when I print the rounded Double, the result is correct. However when I save these Double to an array and print the Double, the result becomes many decimal place.

What should I do to force only 2 decimal Double in the array?

For example:

```
Double -> 2.344563343534   // Original value 

rounded -> 2.35            // Rounded value I want
```

After I save the rounded Double to array and print:

```
Double in array -> 2.34444444444444   // I hope this value only in 2 decimal place.
```

Comment: If it _must_ be only 2 decimals you are probably better of with strings but given the result you get the issue is probably something else than rounding, pleas share your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Convert the `Double` to `String` upto 2 decimal places as per requirement.

```
let num = 2.344563343534
let str = String(format: "%.2f", num)
print(str) //"2.34"
```

Now, get the `Double` from `str`,

```
let doubleValue = Double(str)
print(doubleValue) //2.34
```

Comment: If the goal is precision better to use a Decimal to represent it properly

Comment: Thanks guys for all your answers. In my case, round to 2 decimal place is precise enough. I will use @PGDev's solution, and that's the only solution so far I can think of.  And use Decimal is a good idea as well, but I need Double data type, because I will encode these data into JSON file later.